# Find a memory leak in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm trying to find a memory leak in the folowing code. valgrind gives me this:

```
==14160== 1,850 (592 direct, 1,258 indirect) bytes in 9 blocks are definitely lost in loss    record 2 of 5
==14160==    at 0x4904A06: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:149)
==14160==    by 0x405B1F: tsCreate (ticket_set.c:55)
==14160==    by 0x401ECA: test1TS (main.c:62)
==14160==    by 0x40557C: main (main.c:424)
```

and here's the function:

```
TicketSetStatus tsCreate(TicketSet* t, int n, int c) {
    if(t==NULL){
        return TS_CANNOT_CREATE;
    }
    if (n <= 0){
        return TS_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER;
    }

    t->usedTravels = 0;
    t->originalTravels = n;
    t->cost = c;
    t->moneyLeft = n * c;
    //Date time is array of travels:
    t->dates =  malloc(sizeof(DateTime *)* (n)); //todo maybe c99 allows dynamic arrays?
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        t->dates[i] =  malloc(sizeof(char)*GOOD_LENGTH+1);
        if (t->dates[i] == NULL) {
            free(   t->dates);

            return TS_CANNOT_CREATE;
        }
    }

    return TS_SUCCESS;
}

TicketSetStatus tsDestroy(TicketSet* t, int* moneyLeft) {
    if (t == NULL) {
        return TS_FAIL;
    }
    *moneyLeft = (t->cost) * (t->originalTravels-t->usedTravels);

     for (int i = 0; i < t->originalTravels; i++){
        free(t->dates[i]);
    }
    free(t->dates);

    t=NULL; 
    return TS_SUCCESS;
}
```

when the struct is:

```
struct TS_element {
    int usedTravels;
    int originalTravels;
    int cost;
    DateTime* dates;
    int moneyLeft;
};
```

and

```
typedef char* DateType
```

actually playing with free crashes the program more often than not so i'm inclined to live with the memory leak as long as the program functions correctly.

Comment: Just a side note: In `tsDestroy` the assignment `t=NULL;` doesn't do anything, as `t` is a local variable.

Comment: Another note: When allocating in the loop in `tsCreate`, if one allocation fails you free the array `t->dates` but not the entries already allocated.

Comment: By the way, which line in `tsCreate` is line 55?

Comment: Seems like you might just not be calling tsDestroy every time.

Comment: Can you show us the code for test1TS?

Comment: seems to me like Joachim and Vaughn are right

Comment: This'll probably get moved to code review.

Answer (score 1):

How are you using this array of `DateTime`?  If you are stomping on the values later you will get leaks.  Perhaps a confusion about string assignment?  *ie*

```
char someDateValue[] = "2012-08-15";
t->dates[0] = someDateValue;         // Leak -- your allocated string is lost
```

Instead:

```
strcpy( t->dates[0], someDateValue );
```

There is a definite leak in your error condition in `tsCreate`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t->dates[i] =  malloc(sizeof(char)*GOOD_LENGTH+1);
    if (t->dates[i] == NULL) {
        free(t->dates);              // Leak -- every element up to i-1 is lost
        return TS_CANNOT_CREATE;
    }
}
```

Are you calling `tsDestroy` after you've finished with data initialised by `tsCreate`?  Perhaps you're returning from `main` without cleaning up.

If none of this helps, you should post additional code to show how you are using your data structure.

Answer (score 1):

For at least one error you can focus solely on

```
...
t->dates =  malloc(sizeof(DateTime*) * (n));    /* first malloc */
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* call this loop 1 */
    t->dates[i] =  malloc(sizeof(char)*GOOD_LENGTH+1);  /* second malloc */
    if (t->dates[i] == NULL) {  /* test for malloc error */
        free(   t->dates);      /* free the base array/list */

        return TS_CANNOT_CREATE; /* exit function */
    }
}
...
```

The problem is if the second `malloc` fails, the `free` only frees the base (first) malloc. It does **not** free any other memory allocations created by the second malloc
in loop 1, on a previous loop 1 iteration. I.e. if `t->dates[i] = malloc(...` fails when i is equal to 5 then the memory blocks allocated in the iterations 0 to 4 are not freed before exiting the function.

Hopefully that makes sense.

**Update** @paddy is correct in noting the error of `t->dates[0] = someDateValue`
which in this case what that is saying is:

```
char someDateValue[] = "2012-08-15";
```

could also be written in this case as

```
char *someDateValue = "2012-08-15";
```

so that

```
t->dates[0] = someDateValue;
```

simply assigns the pointer of the string, replacing the pointer to the freshly allocated block in the preceding `malloc`.

Ref: If you are still confused you can read the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) question 6.3 [So what is meant by the ``equivalence of pointers and arrays'' in C?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html) as well as the rest of the C FAQ.

And is correct to suggest [str[n]cpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) (or similar [replacements](http://www.courtesan.com/todd/papers/strlcpy.html)) to copy the array *contents* (rather than its pointer) to the freshly allocated memory block.